# Can't auth to Facebook with iOS SDK and native Facebook application

Tags: ios, facebook, authorization

What I have and what're problems occurred:

1. I've one Facebook account with game application (every day people's playing)
2. I've one more Facebook account with test application, that created recently with default settings.
3. I've native Facebook application on my iPod
4. I'm developing iOS application which uses Facebook iOS SDK.

Invalid flow:

If I use App ID/API Key from first application, I open my application and trying to login. Facebook SDK opens native FB application and show me that screen [image]

I press OK and go back to my iOS with such error and without access token:

```
(NSError *) $0 = 0x001710f0 Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)" UserInfo=0x16d4b0 {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedOriginalErrorCode=210}
```

Valid flow:

If I use App ID/API Key from second (test) application, I open my application and trying to login. Facebook SDK opens native FB application and show me that screen [image]

I press OK and go back to my iOS with valid access token.

Settings of applications are the same, I didn't see any differences. This problem occurred if I have native Facebook application. If I haven't it, Facebook SDK opens browser and authorization will be successful with first and second App ID.

If someone had such problem, please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm having the problem as well.  When I replace the app id with one of my own, it seems to be working fine.  Seems like they've possibly included an invalid app id?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I solved the issue.

Actually after changing here and there I found my bundle id was not matching. I have kept the bundle id same in the following 3 places and it worked:

1. The bundle identifier of your project.
2. In your FB a/c the filed named "iOS Bundle ID:" under head Native iOS App.
3. The notification string value in your AppDelegate.m

   `NSString *const FBSessionStateChangedNotification = @"yourbundleid:FBSessionStateChangedNotification";`

Comment: The `FBSessionStateChangedNotification` is a variable in your own code, right? So why does it matter?

Comment: I have an issue logging in and i check that bundle id is correct in the app settings.  Where should i place there notification string value? Thanks!

Comment: I don't have that constant defined that you mention in step 3. Is that wrong?

Comment: @user102008 it appears that the variable's assigned value is simply intended to be unique. You should be able to achieve the same result by namespacing the variable value with your app's files' prefix, e.g. MYSessionStateChangedNotification

Answer (score 4):

I found that I received the same error when I requested the permission: "offline_access".  When I stopped asking for this permission, the error went away.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and my BundleId were both correct, on FB and in my project.

Check that your FB App is enabled in Settings -> Facebook. Mine was disabled (even though I don't remember disabling it) and once I enabled it, it was fixed.

In my test process, I've added and removed my FB App several times from my FB Account, which is linked with my iPhone. It may explain why, magically, my app was disabled.

Comment: And check also that you have the last version of Facebook iOS SDK

Comment: I went to this setting, mine was set to on, but I switched it to off and then back to on and it suddenly work. I don't know if it's coincidental or not!

Comment: Surely not a coincidence ! Glad it helped :)