# FB SDK integration error in device only + IOS SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

i have added app detail on facebook app setting like add bundle id and enable facebook login.

but still i am getting below error:

`error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)" UserInfo=0x1d100770`

```
{
    com.facebook.sdk: ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk: SystemLoginError,
    com.facebook.sdk: ErrorInnerErrorKey=ErrorDomain=NSURLErrorDomainCode=-1202"The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “api.facebook.com” which could put your confidential information at risk."UserInfo=0x1d101ea0{
        NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https: //api.facebook.com/method/auth.iosauthorizeapp,
        NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Wouldyouliketoconnecttotheserveranyway?,
        NSErrorFailingURLKey=https: //api.facebook.com/method/auth.iosauthorizeapp,
        NSLocalizedDescription=Thecertificateforthisserverisinvalid.Youmightbeconnectingtoaserverthatispretendingtobe“api.facebook.com”whichcouldputyourconfidentialinformationatrisk.
    },
    com.facebook.sdk: ErrorSessionKey=<FBSession: 0x1c5a43a0,
    state: FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed,
    loginHandler: 0x0,
    appID: 504044126326670,
    urlSchemeSuffix: ,
    tokenCachingStrategy: <FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 0x1c5d1a70>,
    expirationDate: (null),
    refreshDate: (null),
    attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-3000: 00: 00+0000,
    permissions: (null)> }
```

thanks

Comment: See this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985502/cant-auth-to-facebook-with-ios-sdk-and-native-facebook-application & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177429/ios-6-facebook-sdk-3-1-1-login-error

Comment: Thanks, my issue is, internet is not working properly.