# Facebook Login Only Works in Simulator

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

When my app needs to login to Facebook in the iOS simulator, it works perfectly. But when I run the app on a device, I click the "Login" button, it says "Project would like to access your basic profile info and friends list", I click OK, and nothing happens. I navigate to the Settings, and see that my app is listed there and allowed access. I think that having Facebook installed on this device may be the cause. This is how I present the Login:

```
// Login to Facebook. This is a must-do because the FBPlacePickerViewController will not populate without login
    FBLoginView *loginview = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
    if (!FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
    loginview.frame = CGRectOffset(loginview.frame, 4, 4);

    #ifdef __IPHONE_7_0
    #ifdef __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
    #if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_7_0
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setEdgesForExtendedLayout:)]) {
        loginview.frame = CGRectOffset(loginview.frame, 50, 18);
    } //-1,8
    #endif
    #endif
    #endif

    [self.view addSubview:loginview];
    [loginview sizeToFit];
    }
```

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook login in IOS works on emulator but not on device with native app instaled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21632043/facebook-login-in-ios-works-on-emulator-but-not-on-device-with-native-app-instal)

Comment: @Yarneo That question is a bit different. Thanks though... I guess.